How to make the same object with the same script, but have it output different values each object
Whenever I created 2 objects with the same script, when I update one object they both update
I’ve been working on a model solar system which has a couple of planet game objects that include simplex noise to generate random terrain. I also have multiple values connecting them which I can change to alter said terrain. The problem is when I create a second game object with the same scripts attached, when I go to then change the values of one of the objects, they both get updated the same. What I would like to happen is each ’planet’ object is updated individually, resulting in each one having unique terrain to one another.
Thanks in advance!

the script on multiple object is by default a new instance, so any variables within that are not class variables are unique per item, so health is per enemy not for all..

Could you include the relevant segments of your code? Specifically include your method for creating the second planet, the declaration of the terrain values, and the way you change those values.
My guess is that you've either marked something static where it shouldn't be, or you haven't actually created a deep copy / separate instance of your planet class.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
